# (Elixir/Erlang) How to get the source code file line total numbers from an Erlang beam file?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, beam

Is this information contained in these chunks of the Beam file? Or is there another way?

- References: Erlang [beam_lab](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/beam_lib.html)

[image: beam file chunks]

Answer (score 0):

For a beam file compiled from Erlang, you can get the number of lines like this:

```erlang
{ok,{_ModuleName,[{debug_info,{debug_info_v1,erl_abstract_code, DebugInfoData}}]}} =
   beam_lib:chunks("my_module", [debug_info]).
{ok, Defs} = erl_abstract_code:debug_info(erlang_v1, x, DebugInfoData, []).
{eof, {Lines, _}} = lists:last(Defs).
```

Replace `"my_module"` with the file name of the beam file *without* the `.beam` extension.